# Switching between services after route change

Tags: angular, angular-routing

My app has a lot of components that are almost the same. Every component contains chart with similar options and different data series. All data fetching and manipulation takes place in service.

I've came up with idea that I don't need so many almost the same components and I'll just pass options and series through service. That will reduce a lot of boilerplate. But is this a good practice? Is it better to have 10 services and 10 components or 10 services and 1 component that will change service when the route will change?

Also that is just theory. I've tried to do this but I'm stuck on how to provide another service after route change and then re-init the component. Couldn't find any informations about that, so any advice would be very helpful.

I've recreated this problem on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rkvzc3?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leverage abstract classes, dependency injection and factories, let me explain:
first of all you can create a `Service` abstract class which will be the model for your concrete services and the injected token in your component, then use a `serviceFactory` to inject the concrete service class in the component depending on runtime parameters (such as route path for example)

I did that in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vgrum3?file=src%2Fcomponent%2Ftemplate.component.ts)

You'll see that by navigating to /template the service1 is used and the number 1 is shown.
And by navigating to /template2 the service2 is used and the number 2 is shown

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: It's what I've looked for, but is there a way to destroy previous service on route change?

Comment: @abellay  I think they are removed directly if you provide your service in the component itself no?
Check again the stackblitz I added the increment method and you can increment and then change template, the temp var will be re-initialised

Answer (score 1):

### Yes. It is a good practice to have 1 component and 10 services

If the Contents of the all components are almost same, you can reuse the same component for all your routes. the better approach is to use 1 component and 10 services.

You can decide which services to use to fetch data by using conditions using the data passed to the component as inputs, or you can use another service to hold the current data and series.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the chartId as a route parameter. That way your routing configuration is much more simpler and cleaner:

```
  {
    path: 'template/:chartId',
    component: TemplateComponent,
  },
```

Then in the `TemplateComponent` you subscribe to the `ActivatedRoute` to detect the route parameter changes:

```
  constructor(
    private _service1: Service1Service,
    private _service2: Service2Service,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const selectedChartId = +params['chartId'];
      if (selectedChartId === 1) {
        this.service = this._service1;
      } else {
        this.service = this._service2;
      }
      this.number = this.service.temp;
    });
  }
```

Check this StackBlitz I created based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m3f5do?file=src/component/template.component.ts

Change the chartId from 1 to 2 to see it working: https://angular-ivy-m3f5do.stackblitz.io/template/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use resolvers to send data to a route. I have modified the code a bit so you can parameterize which service can be sent to which route. I am not saying this is the best way but you can try this. You can even maintain a custom store of services instead of instantiating everytime, as have done in `serviceResolvers.ts`

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dyx1nm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)

```
//// app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {
  Service1Resolver,
  Service2Resolver,
} from '../component/serviceResolvers';
import { TemplateComponent } from '../component/template.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'template',
    component: TemplateComponent,
    resolve: {
      service: Service1Resolver, // Customize your service
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'template2',
    component: TemplateComponent,
    resolve: {
      service: Service2Resolver,
    },
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [Service1Resolver, Service2Resolver],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

```
/// serviceResolvers.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  Resolve,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Service1Service } from './service1.service';
import { Service2Service } from './service2.service';

@Injectable()
export class Service1Resolver implements Resolve<any> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return new Service1Service();
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class Service2Resolver implements Resolve<any> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return new Service2Service();
  }
}
```